# En rails no me funciona generate nombre_de:la:gema:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trabajando en Rails instalé la gema devise pero al momento de  generar el componente de dicha gema en mi proyecto con el comando

> rails generate devise:install en el GitBash

[image: Aca una imagen con lo que me retorna al ejecutar elcomando]

Agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: como instalaste la gema?

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que hiciste `bundle install` luego de agregar `gem 'devise'`a tu `Gemfile`? ¿Te sale devise al ejecutar `gem list`? ¿Quizás algún mensaje de error al tratar de instalar la gema? Dato: En SOes se prefiere el texto por sobre las imágenes, para la próxima mejor copia el texto en vez de sacar un pantallazo del mensaje.

Comment: si ciertamente  hice bundle install luego de agregar gem 'devise'a mi Gemfile, pero me aparecia un mensaje de error y dicho mensaje se referia al bundle, pero ya gracias a Dios he resuelto, lo que hice fue instalar la gema de manera clasica por consola(sin escribir nada en el gemfile) despues si agregar gem 'devise'a mi Gemfile, ejecutar bundle y listo funciono. Deseo preguntar algo mas haber si me puedes ayudar, tengo mi carpeta css y js en el directorio de public,y hago el link a application.html.erb hacia la misma y me funciona, pero no me ejecuta el codigo que tengo en un archivo coffee.

Comment: para expresar mejor lo que dije anteriormente, me ejecuta codigo de javascript pero no de coffee. ciertamente porque en el archivo application.js(a quien le hice en enlace  application.html.erb) agrege un policia con codigo js, pero tengo entendido que ese archivo se debe enlazar con los demas archivos, entre ellos, aquel que tiene extension .coffee(donde ya agrege codigo y estaba esperando ver un resultado) Disculpen si no argumento bien lo que quiero dar a entender, estoy empezando en RoR y y aca en SO tambien